# How to access controls which are placed in iframe

Tags: html, iframe

I have a page a.aspx, which has an iframe whose source is ‘controlsPage.aspx’
Now referring a websource control object I am trying to find controls of ‘controlsPage.aspx’ , but the controls are not traceable.

Our Code:

```
wbSource.Navigate("localhost:12122//a.aspx")
Dim frameCollection As HtmlElementCollection = wbSource.Document.Window.Frames("ChildFrame").Document.GetElementsByTagName("Span")
```

Here we are getting count of frameCollection as 0

Main Page -> a.aspx

```
<html>
   <body>
         <iFrame id = “ChildFrame” src = “controlsPage.aspx”>
         </iFrame>
   </body>
</html>
```

Frame Page  controlsPage.aspx

```
<html>
  <body>
        <asp:label Text=”Source Page”/>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. IFrame runs and independent page. You should parse that page at the backend.

Answer (score -1):

```
<html>
   <body>
         <iFrame id = “ChildFrame” src = “controlsPage.aspx”>
         </iFrame>
   </body>
</html>

<html>
  <body>
        <asp:label Text=”Source Page” id="frame_text" />
 </body>
</html>
```

Javascript code (use the below code in the main page) :

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('ChildFrame');
    var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
    var input = innerDoc.getElementById('frame_text');
```

Comment: You probably didn't notice the OP is using a server side language, not client side (Javascript).